# RegEx for extracting text from a file in NiFi

Tags: java, regex, apache-nifi

I have a JSON response like below and I only want to extract text following text from file using extracttext processor in NIFI. But, it is saying not a valid Java expression.

#### JSON Response

```
"17" : {
  "columnId" : 17,
  "columnName" : "id",
  "value" : "1234:;5678"
}
```

---

```
"17" : {
  "columnId" : 17,
  "columnName" : "id",
  "value" : "1234:;5678"
},
"19" : {
  "columnId" : 19,
  "columnName" : "HelloWorld",
  "value" : "Test 1:;34130"
},
"21" : {
  "columnId" : 21,
  "columnName" : "Testing",
  "value" : "Test"
}
"17" : {
  "columnId" : 17,
  "columnName" : "id",
  "value" : "1299:;6775"
},
"19" : {
  "columnId" : 19,
  "columnName" : "HelloWorld",
  "value" : "Test 2.:;34147"
},
"21" : {
  "columnId" : 21,
  "columnName" : "Testing",
  "value" : "Test"
}
"17" : {
  "columnId" : 17,
  "columnName" : "id",
  "value" : "1299:;6775"
},
"19" : {
  "columnId" : 19,
  "columnName" : "HelloWorld",
  "value" : "Test.:;34147"
},
"21" : {
  "columnId" : 21,
  "columnName" : "globalregions",
  "value" : "Test"
}
```

"

I have tried expression:

```
"17" : {(.*?)\}.
```

It's not working.

Expected result should be :-

```
"17" : {
      "columnId" : 17,
      "columnName" : "id",
      "value" : "1234:;5678"
    }
"17" : {
      "columnId" : 17,
      "columnName" : "id",
      "value" : "1299:;6775"
    }
```

Comment: To have the same key in json object is quite strange .. {} is a spec symbols for regexp. You have to escape them `\{`. And you aren't managing spaces...

Comment: Just use a JSON parser like Jackson / Gson

Comment: @Lino, json parser will collapse all repeating values in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally you should have unique keys for json object.

and in your json there are several keys `"17"` in the same object...

however the following regexp should work for your json: `"17"\s*:\s*\{[^}]*\}`

you can try it: https://regex101.com/r/8RiPHu/1/